# how to correctly import urls.py from app?

Tags: django, django-3.0

This is probably pretty simple but I can't get my head around it.  I'm learning Django, have v3.0.4 installed and can't get the URLs from an app to work correctly.

On the project urls.py I have the following:

**Project\urls.py:**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.urls import include
from AppTwo import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('', include('AppTwo.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

I've created an app named "AppTwo" and have the following urls.py and views.py in the app:

**AppTwo\urls.py:**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('/help', views.help, name='help'),
]
```

**AppTwo\views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("<em>My Second App</em>")

def help(request):
    return HttpResponse("<em>Help Page!!!</em>")
```

If I browse to http://127.0.0.1:8000/ the index page loads and I see the text "My Second App" as expected.  However if I browse to http://127.0.0.1:8000/help I get page not found 404 error.

I can also browse to the admin page just fine.  So far this is a stock project, the only other change I made after creating it was to the settings.py file to install the "AppTwo" application.  Based on the documentation, this looks like it should work, so what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

yep, knew it was simple.

Changed

```
path('/help', views.help, name='help'),
```

to:

```
path('help/', views.help, name='help'),
```

all good now.